# Visual Studio 2019 "Go to Definition" doesn't go directly to the form main class

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2019

In previous versions of Visual Studio, when i would press F12 (Go to definition) on top a winforms form class, it would send me directly to the designer or to the Form main class (not the designer class). Now, when i press F12 i see this:

[image]

It prompts me to select between one of the 2 partial classes, but it is obvious i don't want to go to de Designer class!

Is there a solution for this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: The fact that that's still a thing 3 years later indicates that for the vast majority of users, it's not a problem. If you install the "Resharper" extension, I think it gives you an option for modifying the behaviour of that function

Comment: i just tried in vs2020, cannot reproduce the problem. from program.cs, i select `Form1` and press F12, goes to the file with `InitializeComponent`.

Comment: @LeiYang That selector appears when you press F12 in the main class (`SomeForm.cs`, e.g., `public partial class Form1 : Form) { }`. Given that it's a partial class, it appears to be a consistent behavior. I *think* this is what the OP means with *press F12 (Go to definition) on top a winforms form class*. I don't know what the following statement means: *send me directly to the designer or to the Form main class (not the designer class)*. I don't see why F12 would show the graphic UI designer.

Comment: @jimi. ok. i think VS is good enough. at least i know where my Form is and I rarely rely on F12 to bring me there.

Comment: When i say "on top a winforms class" y mean in any code that references that form. For example: `var form = new Form1()` . In that case, if i press F12 on top of Form1, it appears the selection screen

Comment: In my tests based on VS2017/2019/2022, the "go to definition" operation for Form got the same result as your screenshot.
Maybe there was an extension in previous versions of visual studio?

Comment: What version of Visual Studio were you using before？

Comment: i was using Vs2017 before

Comment: Maybe posting the question on the [Visual Studio Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/search?space=8) can help you out.